# How to render a column header with both text and a tooltip icon in Fabric DetailsList

Tags: office-ui-fabric

In a DetailsList, is it possible to render a specific column header with both text and an icon with a tooltip like this: (I tried with onRenderDetailsHeader but I'm not sure how to handle a specific column).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/vitalius1/pen/YRQwaX) I put together real quick. The only issue is that I couldn't get the info icon rendered as a target for the tooltip. Maybe this will give you a good start.

```
function onRenderDetailsHeader(props, defaultRender?) {
   return defaultRender!({
      ...props,
      onRenderColumnHeaderTooltip: (tooltipHostProps) => {
         return (
            <Fabric.TooltipHost {...tooltipHostProps} />
         )
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: By the way, this doesn't work with versions under 6.102: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/releases/tag/office-ui-fabric-react_v6.102.0

Comment: Good to know. Looked over the PR introducing this feature and it seems that this is an opt-in behavior as it's not wanted by default.

Comment: One issue I am running into with this approach is that this seems to prevent the "AccessibleLabel" from getting rendered on the headers. Take a look at https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/d85af4b0eb272cadeb80a9ac71e0552d14653e4e/packages/react/src/components/DetailsList/DetailsColumn.base.tsx, in the "_renderAccessibleLabel()" method. How can I get both the tooltip and the accessible label to show up? Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 3):

A hack way, although the `name` prop is defined as string type, in fact we can pass a ReactNode to it, just need to cast its type to any.

Example code:

```js
import { Tooltip } from 'antd'
import { InfoCircleOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons'

const columns: IColumn[] = [
{
  name: <div>xxx <Tooltip title="tooltip"><InfoCircleOutlined /></Tooltip></div> as any,
  ...
},
...
]

<DetailsList columns={columns} .../>
```

Effects:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My solution is similar to [Vitalie Braga's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10593710/vitalie-braga), but with a more detailed return of the `onRenderColumnHeaderTooltip` you can achieve this functionality. I based populating the `tooltipHostProps.children` from [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620474/can-office-fabric-detailslist-column-headers-be-styled), and you can also see more about styling the tooltip headers there.

One way you can achieve filtering is by looking at the `tooltipHostProps.id` to specify that you only want the tooltip icon on certain column header cells. In your example, the code would look something like the following:

```
function onRenderDetailsHeader(props, defaultRender?) {
   return defaultRender!({
      ...props,
      onRenderColumnHeaderTooltip=(tooltipHostProps) => (
            <>
                <span>
                    {tooltipHostProps?.children}
                </span>
                {tooltipHostProps?.id?.includes('value') &&
                    <span>
                        <TooltipHost content={"This is the tooltip"}>
                            <Icon iconName="info" />
                        </TooltipHost>
                    </span>
                }
            </>
        )}
   );
};
```