# How to make a DetailsList header shows tooltip

Tags: office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, fluentui-react, office-ui-fabric-react

How to configure detailsHeader properly to make it show tooltip for the header text?
In each column, I've added ariaLabel, name, key, fieldName and have tried the top answer in this post but does not work: [How to render a column header with both text and a tooltip icon in Fabric DetailsList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53321904/how-to-render-a-column-header-with-both-text-and-a-tooltip-icon-in-fabric-detail)

I am using "@fluentui/react": "^8.11.1"

Answer (score 1):

```
private renderFixedDetailsHeader: IRenderFunction<IDetailsHeaderProps> = (props, defaultRender) => {
    if (!props) {
        return null;
    }
    const onRenderColumnHeaderTooltip: IRenderFunction<IDetailsColumnRenderTooltipProps> =
        (tooltipHostProps: any) => {
            return (
                <TooltipHost content={tooltipHostProps.column.name}>
                    {tooltipHostProps.column.name}
                </TooltipHost>
            );
        }
    return (
        <Sticky stickyPosition={StickyPositionType.Header} isScrollSynced>
            {defaultRender!({
                ...props,
                onRenderColumnHeaderTooltip,
            })}
        </Sticky>
    );
}
```

// render Detail Header

```
public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <ShimmeredDetailsList
            columns={this.state.columns}
            items={this.state.items}
            onRenderItemColumn={this.props.onRenderItemColumn}
            enableShimmer={this.props.isLoading}
            setKey={this.props.setKey}
            key={this.props.setKey}
            selectionMode={SelectionMode.none}
            onShouldVirtualize={() => false}
            onRenderRow={this.props.showBlueBackgroundGrid ? this._onRenderRow : undefined}
            onRenderDetailsHeader={this.renderFixedDetailsHeader}
        />
    );
}
```

// Render detail list.

The fluent UI provides us onRenderDetailHeader to create our own custom header. You can return the custom header with tooltip or your own styles also.

Comment: This solution works. But if I have a Detailslist where I can select (single or multi) the first column has no header, or other way round: for the first time the method onRenderColumnHeaderTooltip ist called the property 'column' of tooltipHostProps is not defined and an error will be thrown.
So: 
if (!tooltipHostProps.column) return null;